# Element.update() prototype function not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs

I was using `Element.innerHTML` but IE (8,9,10) doesn't like it, so I switched to `Element.insert()`, but IE doesn't like it either. Then decided to try with `Element.update()` - nope again!

Searched around and found out that `.update()` is actually the working replacement of `.innerHTML` for IE... Tried with passing a variable or even a direct string as parameter to the function - "nuh uh" says IE.

**script**

```
var dropdownHTML = '<option>Some text</option>';
$('size_list').update('<form ><select id="dropdown_options"></select></form>');
for (var element in jsonResponse){
  dropdownHTML += '<option>'+ someString + '</option>';
  ...
}
$('dropdown_options').update(dropdownHTML);
```

**source**

```
<div id="size_list" style="float:right;">
</div>
```

Needless to say, it all works in FF and Chrome. I made a working solution with `jQuery.html()` but my whole document is built up with `prototype.js` and I would not like to mix the 2 things.

Any suggestions?

Comment: just a for loop, not that important in this case, because the script breaks on the `.update()` before the loop. I will update the code snippet with the original look.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak - my aim is to NOT use jQuery. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest answer here is to use the `Option` constructor rather than setting the HTML of the `select` element.

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
var select = document.createElement('select');
select.id = "dropdown_options";
select.options.add(new Option("Some text"));
for (/*...whatever your loop is...*/) {
    select.options.add(new Option("text of the option", "optional value of the option"));
}
form.appendChild(select);
$("size_list").appendChild(form);
```

Note that you use `add` (rather than `push`) with the options collection (it's not an array; some implementations have `push`, but `add` is more reliable).